# In which US state does a given geographic point fall?

Tags: gps

I wish to determine the US state and county in which a given geographic point (GPS coords known) falls.  I believe that I can obtain data as to the coordinates of the corners of states and counties but I then need an algorithm to calculate in which state and county the point falls.

I am not a Java or C user but I am a very experienced programmer in Panorama (provue.com), a database management system with a very comprehensive and powerful programming language.  So I need access to a generically-defined algorithm.

michael

Comment: If the google maps api is ok to be used, you can save yourself a lot of work.

Answer (score 1):

First you should have a set of polygons, each one corresponding to a US state like in http://www.nws.noaa.gov/geodata/catalog/national/html/us_state.htm

Then you can use the following algorithm given in http://www.ecse.rpi.edu/Homepages/wrf/Research/Short_Notes/pnpoly.html#The C Code

```
int pnpoly(int nvert, float *vertx, float *verty, float testx, float testy)
{
  int i, j, c = 0;
  for (i = 0, j = nvert-1; i < nvert; j = i++) {
    if ( ((verty[i]>testy) != (verty[j]>testy)) &&
     (testx < (vertx[j]-vertx[i]) * (testy-verty[i]) / (verty[j]-verty[i]) + vertx[i]) )
       c = !c;
  }
  return c;
}
```

nvert: Number of vertices in the polygon. Whether to repeat the first vertex at the end is discussed below.

vertx, verty: Arrays containing the x- and y-coordinates of the polygon's vertices.

testx, testy: X- and y-coordinate of the test point.

Comment: +1 The beauty of this method is this will work on any polygon you choose, so it can be reused to check points within counties or nations or any arbitrary polygon

Answer (score 0):

Quick & dirty: 
you can use [*this project*](http://www.ngs.noaa.gov/cgi-bin/spc_getpc.prl) in the following way as HTTP request:
http://www.ngs.noaa.gov/cgi-bin/spc_getpc.prl?LatBox=N385930.99999&LonBox=W0985930.99999

and parse the response to extract the state.